# Raspberry Pi Webcam Motion Snapshot

Tags: pi-2, webcam, motion

i'm doing a motion (streaming webcam content) project and i want to know how can i take a snapshot with a terminal command.

```
wget http://localhost:8080/?action=snapshot -O output.jpg
```

This does not seem to work properly. It outputs a jpg, but it just keeps downloading forever. Is there any other command or is it not possible to take a snapshot on command (i'm using a button for this). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/).
`sudo apt-get install fswebcam` to install it, then
`fswebcam image.jpg` to snap a shot. There's a bunch of settings you can set to, like resolution.